# ansible not working become

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I'm using task ansible

playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: servers
  remote_user: user
  become: True
  become_user: user
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name:
  ┆ ┆ copy:
  ┆ ┆ ┆ src: editProxy.sh
  ┆ ┆ ┆ dest: /tmp/editProxy.sh
  ┆ ┆ ┆ mode: 0755

  ┆ - name: run edit proxy settings for apt 
  ┆ ┆ command: /tmp/editProxy.sh
```

editProxy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -q "old_proxy" /etc/apt/apt.conf; then
    sed -i 's/old_proxy/new_proxy/g' /etc/apt/apt.conf;
fi
```

run playbook
    ansible-playbook palybook.yml --extra-vars='ansible_become_pass=passwd

script copy to servers, and not return error

changed: [10.1.1.1]

But changes on the server do not happen, if you run the script manually on the server, the changes take place. What could be the problem

Comment: Which version of ansible do you have?

Comment: What are your mount options on the /tmp ? Do you have 'noexec' in those options? If yes, it means that nobody (including root) can run any script or binary located in /tmp

Comment: ansible --version
ansible 2.4.0.0

Comment: /tmp is not a member of the section

Comment: /dev/mapper/vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense:

```
  remote_user: user
  become: True
  become_user: user
  become_method: sudo
```

Your playbook told ansible to connect to the remote server as the user `user`, but instead of `sudo` to `root`, your playbook has specified to `sudo` to the same user `user`! In some other comment you seem to expect your playbook to run as root. If that is the case then you need to remove `become_user: user` so that ansible will `sudo` to `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than uploading a script and executing that to run sed to replace a string in a configuration file, have considered using the Ansible native [replace module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/replace_module.html)? For instance something along the line of:

```
  - name: Modify proxy settings for apt
    replace:
      path: /etc/apt/apt.conf
      regexp: 'old_proxy'
      replace: 'new_proxy'
      backup: yes
```

Comment: it is not work, error create file backup

Comment: Is your `become_user: user` a user different from `root`? Because then your problem is essentially on of insufficient user permissions to access a file owned by root.

Comment: become_user can make sudo su and run sudo editProxy.sh complete

Comment: ssh user@host echo "pass" | sudo   -S editProxy.sh - not work

Answer (score 0):

Try ansible.builtin.script out!
[Runs a local script on a remote node after transferring it.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html#ansible-builtin-script-runs-a-local-script-on-a-remote-node-after-transferring-it)